# If x = 1:10 and y = list(x,x), then the memory size of y is equivalent to two times the memory size of x

Tags: r

If x = 1:10 and y = list(x,x), then the memory size of y is equivalent to two times the memory size of x.

This is one of my r homework question, but I cannot figure out why this is false.

```
> x=10
> x=1:10
> list(x,x)
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `object.size` function to report the space allocated for an object

```
x <- 1:10
y <- list(x,x)

object.size(x)
88 bytes
object.size(y)
232 bytes
```